# How to get value of checked checkbox (in footer of jqgrid) and send to controller?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, checkbox, jqgrid

I have checkbox in footer of jqgrid and want to send value of checkbox to controller when click on button(Send Command). 
[image]

When a row is selected and click button send command,
In addition to its value, the Check box is sent (selected or not selected)
My code:

```
 .jqGrid('navButtonAdd', '#pager',
                       {
                       caption: "Send Command ", buttonicon:"ui-  icon-signal-diag", title: "Send Command ",
                            onClickButton: function () {
                                var selRow =    jQuery("#list").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selarrrow');  //get selected rows
                                var dataToSend = JSON.stringify(selRow);
                                if (selRow == 0) {
                                    // display error message because no row is selected
                                    $.jgrid.viewModal("#" + 'alertmod_' + this.p.id,
                                        { gbox: "#gbox_" +   $.jgrid.jqID(this.p.id), jqm: true });
                                    $("#jqg_alrt").focus();
                                }
                                else {
                                    $.ajax({
                                        url: '@Url.Action("Index", "AddSMS")',
                                        type: 'POST',
                                        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                                        data: dataToSend,
                                        dataType: 'json',
                                        success: function (result) {
                                            alert('success');
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        })
        $("#pager_left table.navtable tbody tr").append( // here 'pager' part or #pager_left is the id of the pager
'<td><div><input type="checkbox" class="myMultiSearch" id="WithSetting" />Setting </div></td>');
```

I can send data of row but i don't know how to send value of checkbox???

Comment: I'm not a jQuery expert, but I guess you should start by giving your checkbox a `value` attribute, e.g. `<input type="checkbox" class="myMultiSearch" id="WithSetting" value="1" />`. This is the value that will be sent through your form when the checkbox is activated. You should then be able to retrieve it in your jQuery script.

Comment: yes I should give value of checkbox but how to send value to controller? i can send only my row selected not value of chechbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You send it as a URL parameter. Change:

```
url: '@Url.Action("Index", "AddSMS")',
```

to

```
url: '@Url.Action("Index", "AddSMS")' + '?cbChecked=' + $("input.myMultiSearch").is(":checked"),
```

Then you should be able to update `Index` in your `AddSMS` controller to:

```
public ActionResult Index(long[] selrow, bool cbChecked) 
{ 
    if (cbChecked) 
    {
        //this should run if the checkbox has been checked
    }
//......
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. In my controller i get array of int and don't have any boolean???

Comment: @mahdisdezfouli  Try update `Index` with `Index(....., int[] data, bool cbChecked)`

Comment: @mahdisdezfouli can you post the `Index()` line from your controller?

Comment: I don't undrestand what you mean?

Comment: @mahdisdezfouli In your `AddSMS` controller is a method definition for `Index`. Something like `public ActionResult Index(object model, int[].........) { ..... }`. I would like for you to add that line of code to your question so that I can see what data types Index is expecting so that I can help you update it.

Comment: public ActionResult Index(long[] selrow, bool cbChecked)
        {
            if (selRow[0].ToString() == "")
            {

Comment: public ActionResult Index(long[] selRow, bool cbChecked)
        {
            if (selRow[0].ToString() == "" && cbChecked==true)
            {
            }
            else if (selRow[0].ToString() == "" && cbChecked == false)
            {
            }
            return MessageBox.Show("success", MessageType.Success, modal: true);
        }

Comment: @mahdisdezfouli I updated my answer. I realized you were calling `JSON.stringify()` but I was reading that as `JSON.parse()`. You do not need to `stringify()` the object. jQuery will do that automatically.

Comment: I use this code but when click button don't work and don't run index of controller.

Comment: @mahdisdezfouli Ok, since I cannot test, I am trying to find the correct combination.. one moment, I have another update to make..

Comment: Thanks for taking time. I realize when call Index with bool input it don't work . and it run just with int or long input.

Comment: @mahdisdezfouli When you say "won't work", is there a JavaScript error? Or an error in the controller? Or is the boolean value always false?

Comment: when I use index two input it don't work. Also when i delete stringify() and i use second update it don't work even i use one input in index.

Comment: boolean value don't send in index

Comment: @mahdisdezfouli put dataToSend back like you had it and add stringify back then change ` '@Url.Action("Index", "AddSMS")'` to ` '@Url.Action("Index", "AddSMS")' + '?cbChecked=' + $("input.myMultiSearch").is(":checked")`

Comment: It work correctly. Thank you very much. Your help was useful.

Comment: @mahdisdezfouli I have completed updating my answer to include the option that you were able to get working. I would appreciate if you can mark this as the answer if it helped you to solve the issue. Thank you.

Comment: Thank You very much. Certainly do it.